# How to make ASP.NET Core Web API on .NET 5 run on Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I am having an issue when trying to publish a Web API running on .NET 5 on Azure
I keep getting a [image: 404 error]

Even the default ASP.NET Core Web API template is failing when deployed to Azure.

I already set Azure to use early access on .NET 5 and I even tried self-contained deployment.

Ignore the fact the screenshot is accessing `index.html`, that was just a test, same happens accessing the routes of any actions in the controllers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to break this to you, but WebAPI's don't have HTML pages. They only have controllers. If you want to have documentation pop up, I would get Swagger, then you can go to `https://example.com/swagger` and see your controllers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio If you want a web site with HTML content, then *don't* choose the WebAPI option when creating your project.

Comment: hehe, yeah I know, posted the wrong screenshot, that is not the issue it happened even with the default route, no static files. Turns out Azure requires you to have an additional wwwroot folder with js, and cs, even if you have a Web API that is supposed to have no static files

Comment: I've been writing WebAPIs in Azure for 4 years and have never had to have any `wwwroot` directory or any static content what-so-ever. The default WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2019 is all you need.

Comment: Neither did I, until I released this specific project in .NET 5. Default Web API projects on .NET Core 3.1 are deploying just fine.

Comment: `Turns out Azure required me to add an additional wwwroot with js, and css files, even when my project is configured to use endpoints only` Never heard of requiring this additional wwwroot folder for API project on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the API template is a project template for creating a RESTful HTTP service, as @Andy mentioned, WebAPI project usually does not serving HTML pages.

If you really want to serve a `index.html` page in your WebAPI project, you can try:

1)create a `wwwroot` folder in your project and put `index.html` within it

[image]

2)call the `UseStaticFiles` method in `Startup.Configure`, which enables static files to be served

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    //your code here...

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    //...
```

For more information about serving static files, please check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> it happened even with the default route, no static files.

You can try to access your API endpoint with your actual route that you configured, that might look like below.

```
https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/{controller_name}/{action_name?}
```

Or

```
https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/{controller_name}/{action_name?}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to fix the issue.
I compare to other project I had deployed in the past and to a Blazor in .NET 5 I have deployed too.
Turns out Azure required me to add an additional wwwroot with js, and css files, even when my project is configured to use endpoints only, and is not using static files at all.

Answer (score 0):

As of yesterday the issue is not happening anymore